# How to verify number of records using capybara

Tags: html, ruby, cucumber, capybara

I am using capybara along with cucumber on a Rails 2.3.9 project.

I have users index page and I have two records there. Using capybara how do I assert that there are only two records in the page.

HTML structure is like this

```
<div class='records'>
  <li>record 1<li>
  <li>record 2 </li>
</div>
```

Answer (score 49, accepted):

This should do the trick for your Cucumber step definition:

```
page.has_css?("div.records li", :count => 2)
```

There's also `page.has_xpath?` (but I don't understand xpath)

If you're using Rspec you can phrase it the Rspec way with:

```
page.should have_css("div.records li", :count => 2)
```

I had to solve a very similar problem just yesterday; here's the full step definition I ended up with.

```
Then /^I should see only (\d+) tasks$/ do |number_of_tasks|
  page.should have_css("table tr.task", :count => number_of_tasks.to_i)
end
```

Comment: `page.should have_select("table tr", :count => 2)` also works

Answer (score 0):

Updated code would look like:

```
page.should have_css('div.records li', count: 2)
```

and then you can check:

```
within('div.records li') do
   expect(page).to have_text('record 1')
   expect(page).to have_text('record 2')
end
```